# Add multiple columns to MultiIndex dataframe from multiple scalar values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Given the following MultiIndex `df`

```
| foo     |        |
| one     | two    |
| ------- | ------ |
| "12345" | "1235" |
| "12345" | "1345" |
```

I would like to append more columns that are each all filled with the same value, but this value is different for different columns. I have these values stored the following way as a MultiIndex pandas Series `se`:

```
|bar | 0  | 2 |
|    | 1  | 3 |
 ...  ...  ...
|    | 99 | 7 |
```

The result would look like this:

```
| foo      |          | bar |     | ... |     |
| one      | two      | 0   | 1   | ... | 99  |
| -------- | -------- | --- | --- | ... | --- |
| "12345"  | "1235"   | 2   | 3   | ... | 7   |
| "12345"  | "1345"   | 2   | 3   | ... | 7   |
```

I have found this very ugly solution to my problem...

```
for i in range(len(se)):
    df["bar", i] = se[i]
```

... that also gives me a warning:

`PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling`frame.insert`many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use newframe = frame.copy()`

Have been trying to find the solution to this for a while now, thanks in advance for useful answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use :

```
tmp = se.to_frame().T

out = df.join(tmp.loc[tmp.index.repeat(len(df))].reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output :

```
print(out)

     foo       bar      
     one   two   0  1 99
0  12345  1235   2  3  7
1  12345  1345   2  3  7
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. I had to set `tmp.index = df.index` before joining on top of that because my `df.index` did not go like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..